Operator names that ignore parentheses
As \dim is set like an operator name, just like \sin, when we write \dim(X+Y) the spacing that we get in \dim X is omitted. This works perfectly for \sin, of course, but is not really correct for the dimension.
Is there a to define a command like \dim to behave as an operatorname except for that special rule of spacing?
One can say \dim{}(X+Y), for example: that gets the spacing correct… but urgh.

why do you say it is incorrect?

I heartily disagree. Why should \dim behave differently from \sin? I really can't find a reason.
Anyway, you can ruin your math typesetting  with the following definition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\dim}{e{_}}{%
  \operatorname{dim}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}

$\dim X$

$\dim(X+Y)$

$\dim_F(X+Y)$

\end{document}


This adds an empty Ord atom (but only after an optional subscript).
If you don't want the thin space when a subscript is present, do
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\dim}{e{_}}{%
  \operatorname{dim}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{{}}{_{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\dim X$

$\dim(X+Y)$

$\dim_F(X+Y)$

\end{document}



Quick hack: You can peek ahead with \@ifnextchar to conditionally add a {}.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\orig@dim\dim
\renewcommand{\dim}{\orig@dim\@ifnextchar({{}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\sin X$

$\dim X$

$\sin(X+Y)$

$\dim(X+Y)$

$\dim_k(X+Y)$

\end{document}


For what it's worth, I think the unchanged appearance looks better.
